# Is it possible to write data to HDFS outside of MR job and still query with Hive?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am using skeleton code for an MR job. This job's inputs and outputs are all NullWritable. I must use this skeleton, but I must also write data from this job to HDFS. Furthermore, the data I write must be queryable through Hive.

Is there a way to do this?

I know how to navigate & manipulate files through the hadoop filesystem API in Java. The main issue I'm having is with making these files queryable through Hive.

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879557/hadoop-hive-query-files-from-hdfs)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create an external Hive table that points to a location in HDFS. Then have your MR job write files to that same location in a format consistent with the Hive scheme (or vice-versa, create the Hive schema to match the expected formate of the output of the MR job).

```
create external table if not exists dbname.tblname 
(field1 STRING
,field2 STRING
,field3 STRING)
row format delimited
lines terminated by ‘\n’
fields terminated by ‘,’
stored as textfile
location ‘hdfs_path’;
```

Then if your MR job writes a CSV file with field1, field2, and field3 to hdfs_path, they will be queryable through this external table.